# Why does `toString()` method on a null object in Dart not throw an exception?

Tags: dart, type-conversion, nullable, non-nullable

I have the following code snippet in Dart:

```
void main(List<String> args){
 String? test1 = null;
 String test2 = test1.toString();
 print(test1);
 print(test2);
}
```

I expected the second `print()` statement to output an empty string because `test2` is declared as a non-nullable `String`. However, it outputs “null” instead. Can someone explain why this is happening?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because `null` is still an instance. Sole instance of class `Null` and it has `toString()` method implemented. See here for details: [Null class](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.7.1/dart-core/Null-class.html)